# Best way to log all user activities in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to log all the activities of the user in active admin including all member action requests.  So what is the best method to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a gem called [public_activity](https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity), which is meant to log all **activities**.

All you have to do, the action you want to track, you need to add something like the following

```
Activity.create({user_id: current_user.id, action: action_name, data: "if you want to show what changed"})
```

You also have the option to use [papertrail](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Auditing-via-paper_trail-%28change-history%29).

Answer (score 0):

There is this other gem called [papertrail](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail), with which you can track changes to your models, for auditing or versioning. Then I have a custom action for every model I track to see the history changes of the model inside Active Admin.